# How can i send a binary file via serial in linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, cat, stty

I want to control a hdmi matrix switch via serial connection.
In Windows i already tried it successful by the following steps:

Decode the necessary HEX from a simple textfile to a binary:

```
certutil -decodehex on.txt on.bin
```

Then configure the mode for my comport:

```
MODE COM1:19,n,8,1
copy on.bin \\.\com1 /b
```

Now i try to do the same in linux (debian). Since the files are binary i figured i can reuse them, so i transferred them to the linux system and tried the following to configure the comport:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 19200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

And sending the binary:

```
cat on.bin > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But that won't do anything.´

EDIT:

It's a different PC, but the USB2Serial Converter ist the same. 
`lsusb` gives me:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter`

dmesg shows

`[    5.070075] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    5.072824] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
[    5.073476] usb 1-9: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0`

Comment: Try adding `raw` to your **stty** command line.  BTW "*binary"* is an adjective, not a noun.  So to be clear you should write that you are trying to send a binary file.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I changed the title. I added the suggested `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 19200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb raw`. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: The **cat** command works for me, so you have to provide a lot more info to determine why it isn't working for you.  Is the Debian PC a different machine from the Windows PC?  Same USB adapter?

Comment: It's a different PC, but the USB2Serial Converter ist the same. 
`lsusb` gives me: 
`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter`
`dmesg` shows 
`[    5.070075] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic`  

`[    5.072824] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart`  

`[    5.073476] usb 1-9: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0`